# ORACLE SQL Show all date/time ranges if another timestamp does not fall in between this range

Tags: sql, oracle, date-range

One table DT with different timestamps:

**date_time**

```
22/01/2013 22:30
16/10/2012 11:20
30/03/2012 20:50
```

Another Table TIMEFRAMES with a start date and end date:

```
SDT                     EDT
22/01/2013 23:30        22/01/2013 23:40
22/01/2013 20:30        22/01/2013 20:40  
22/01/2013 22:10    X   22/01/2013 22:40 <--should filtered out because
                                            one of the timestamps(values from DT table)
                                            is between SDT & EDT
16/10/2012 11:00        16/10/2012 11:10
16/10/2012 11:00    X   16/10/2012 11:40 <--should filtered out because
                                            one of the timestamps(values from DT table)
                                            is between SDT & EDT
```

So desired result would be all the rows from TIMEFRAMES table exept those rows where any timestamp (date_time) from DT table does NOT fall in between the timeframes from table TIMEFRAMES

```
SDT                   EDT
22/01/2013 23:30      22/01/2013 23:40
22/01/2013 20:30      22/01/2013 20:40    
16/10/2012 11:00      16/10/2012 11:10
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/340a8/3

Comment: Note that in your fiddle, the final TIMEFRAMES record has a SDT from 2013 and a EDT from 2012.

Comment: Good point... Should be 2012.  **[corrected fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/e03b5/4)**

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
select * from timeframes f where not exists
(select 1 from dt where dt.date_time between f.sdt and f.edt)
```

Comment: +1 for the best, most readable and simplest solution. Always keep it simple.

Answer (score 1):

```
select sdt, edt 
from timeframes t
left join dt on (dt.date_time between t.sdt and t.edt)
where dt.date_time is null;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ef3a8/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a left outer join and aggregation:

```
select tf.sdt, tf.edt, COUNT(*), COUNT(dt.date_time)
from timeframes tf left outer join
     dt
     on dt.date_time between tf.sdt and tf.edt
group by tf.sdt, tf.edt
having COUNT(*) <> COUNT(dt.date_time)
```

The `having` clause is checking whether all the dts are in the range.

Comment: I think you don't need those counts. it is enough to not have any dt.date_time values.